# Refreshing the xpage document & showing the computed fields immediately without closing & reopening the xpage document

Tags: xpages

I am working with xpages and need a unique number to be generated for each document. After saving the document, I want the user to be on the same page viewing the generated number. For this I have used the a action group on the submit button - 1) first action is a simple action which is saving the document. 2) Next action is script editor where I am calling my number generation agent 3) The last one is a simple action which is changing the current document mode from Edit to Read so that the user is still on the same xpage document after saving. But I see that the document is saved properly and also changed to read mode but I cant see the number generated. But if I close the document & open it again I see that the number is generated. I want this number to be shown without closing & reopening the document. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to attempt this, post the code you try, and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Comment: For info, to get at the code to post, go to the source pane.

Answer (score 0):

If you're updating the backend Document datasource, you'll need to either fully reload the page or close and re-open. Try setting the unique reference on the dominoDocument datasource and re-saving that. Alternatively, build the relevant URL to the XPage with the relevant `documentId` parameter and redirect accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a Full Upload at your onClick event or a partial Upload.

With the partial Update will update just one element of your page, if your computed fields are inside this element they will be updated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0DA7.png

Comment: Thank you but I tried with Full update also.. its still not working :-(

Comment: hmm, ok, so you can try something like this, go on your xpages or custom control > Properties > Data > Add Domino Document

The Data source name come by default document1, with this name you can call your document in javascript as a NotesXspDocument, in form choose the form that your document uses.

NotesXspDocument has somes functions like getItemValue(FieldName), getItemValueString(FieldName), replaceItemValue(FieldName,NewValue) and save(), use this functions in your script server side for controll of your document instead of your agent.

Comment: Now finally go into your xpage or custom controll and create one field go on Properties > Data, at data source choose your document1 Domino Document and bind to the name of the Field at your form, so that field on the xpage page will be binded to a field of your document, finish with a full update or a partial update at the field or at some element that the field are inside.

Comment: Hope this help, if so please check the green check, thanks